# Rails: Undefined method in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, methods, rails-activerecord

I'd like to convert a unix time to human time before saving my object from an api.
But I cannot access to my method `format date`, it raise me :

> undefined method `format_date' for 1467738900000:Fixnum

My model :

```
class Conference < ActiveRecord::Base
validates_presence_of :title, :date
validates :date, :uniqueness => true

 def self.save_conference_from_api
    data = self.new.data_from_api
    self.new.parisrb_conferences(data).each do |line|
      conference = self.new
      conference.title = line['name']
      conference.date = line['time'].format_date
      conference.url = line['link']
      if conference.valid?
        conference.save
      end
    end
    self.all
 end

 def format_date
   DateTime.strptime(self.to_s,'%Q')
 end
```

Comment: As the error suggests, `line['time']` is a number, not an instance of your class `Conference`. And the reason is not in the code you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`line['time']` is not an instance of your `Conference` class, so you can't call `format_date` method on it. Instead, for example, you can make `format_date` a class method:

```
def self.format_date str
  DateTime.strptime(str.to_s,'%Q')
end
```

And then call it like this:

```
conference.date = format_date(line['time'])
```

The other option is to use a `before_validation` callback (*attribute assignment will be as follows: `conference.date = line['time']` and there is no need for `format_date` method*):

```
before_validation -> r { r.date = DateTime.strptime(r.date.to_s,'%Q') }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the date in unix time milliseconds. You can do like this

```
conference.date = DateTime.strptime(line['time'].to_s,'%Q')
```

Comment: Thank you for the proposition it was my first idea but I wanted to do a method to do it.